# json data get only the last value

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I'm trying to get JSON data and insert these data into SQLite Database. 
There are a lot of data in the JSON url. But, my app get only the last value.

Here is my code to get JSON Data

```
protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    restaurants = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_RESTAURANTS);

                    for (int i = 0; i < restaurants.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = restaurants.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject restaurant = c.getJSONObject("Restaurant");
                        id = restaurant.getString("id");
                        name = restaurant.getString("name");
                        image = restaurant.getString("image");
                        description = restaurant.getString("description");
                        address = restaurant.getString("address");
                        phone = restaurant.getString("phone");


                        //Inserting json data into SQLite db
                        db.insertIntoRestaurantsTable(id,name,image,description,address,phone);
                        Log.d("Insert:", "Inserting....");


                        HashMap<String, String> jsonRestaurantData = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        jsonRestaurantData.put("id", id);
                        jsonRestaurantData.put("name", name);
                        jsonRestaurantData.put("image", image);
                        jsonRestaurantData.put("description", description);
                        jsonRestaurantData.put("address", address);
                        jsonRestaurantData.put("phone", phone);

                        arraylist.add(jsonRestaurantData);

                        return arraylist;



                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Here is my JSON Sample

```
{
restaurants: [
{
Restaurant: {
id: "5",
name: "Dummy Name 5",
image: "443366291404304960DSCF6532.JPG",
description: "Dummy Description 5",
address: "Dummy Address 5",
phone: "1234"
}
},
{
Restaurant: {
id: "4",
name: "Dummy Name 4",
image: "867352851406598423IMG_0433.JPG",
description: "Dummy Description 4",
address: "Dummy Description 4",
phone: "01111222"
}
},
{
Restaurant: {
id: "3",
name: "Dummy Name 3",
image: "6065339moon.jpg",
description: "Dummy description 3",
address: "Dummy Description 3",
phone: "092131232"
}
},
```

After debugging, only the following latest data is inserted into SQLite. All the other are left.

```
Restaurant: {
 id: "5",
 name: "Dummy Name 5",
 image: "443366291404304960DSCF6532.JPG",
 description: "Dummy Description 5",
 address: "Dummy Address 5",
 phone: "1234"
 }
},
```

Something wrong with my looping to get JSON data??
Please help me.

Here is my database code.

```
public void insertIntoRestaurantsTable(String restaurant_id, String name, String image, String description, String address, String phone )
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        insertValues.put("_id",restaurant_id);
        insertValues.put("_name",name);
        insertValues.put("_image",image);
        insertValues.put("_description",description);
        insertValues.put("_address",address);
        insertValues.put("_phone", phone);

        db.insert(RESTAURANT_TABLE_NAME, null, insertValues);

    }
```

Comment: please show the code for `db.insertIntoRestaurantTable()`. you seem to be overwriting the entry every time you insert instead of creating a new one.

Comment: updated with insertIntoRestaurantTable()

Comment: the prblem was elsewhere. see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

forget about my comment. your problem is that the return statement is inside the for loop instead of outside of it. so after the first iteration, the method will return. you are not getting the last element, but the first.
instead of this:

```
         for(){
                try{
                    ...
                    arraylist.add(jsonRestaurantData);

                    return arraylist;

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
```

you need to do this:

```
         for(){
                try{
                    ...
                    arraylist.add(jsonRestaurantData);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           }
           return arraylist;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is fixed now. :)